# XSLT How to print all attributes inside an element: <node id="" name="" random=""></node>

Tags: html, xml, xslt

The only answers I come across is how to list the value of the node and child nodes itself. What I would like to know is how I can print all the values inside the node tag itself.

XML (there can be more books within catalog)

```
<data>
<info>
    <catalog Id="1111" Locale="en_GB">
        <books>
            <book id="01" Name="Title 1" Author="John Doe"></book>
            <book id="02" Name="Title 2" Author="Jane Doe"></book>
        </books>
```

What I currently have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body> 

<xsl:for-each select="data/info/catalog">
   <xsl:value-of select="@Id" />
   <xsl:value-of select="/books/book/@Name"/>
</xsl:for-each>

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Specifically, I would like the output to be:

```
Catalog Id: 1111

Attributes:
id: 01
Name: Title 1
Author: John Doe

id: 02
Name: Title 2
Author: Jane Doe
```

The reason it's being done this way because I have dozens upon dozens of values and it's easier to fit them inside the node tag itself instead of creating hundreds of sub-sub-subchilds.

Comment: The "values inside a node tag" are called *attributes*. And the "node tag" is an *element*. There are no tags in XSLT; it works on the parsed tree, not on the markup document.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank you for explaining, I have xml files which have node names as entities and attributes. So it was leaving me confused. I'll rename the title so it will be easier for people in the future to find.

Comment: "The only answers I come across". Seriously, is that how you learn the language, by looking for questions and answers? That's a very inefficient way of mastering the technology. Do some reading.

Comment: @MichaelKay I read documentation and watch video explanations as well. Forums and sites like StackOverflow is just another part in the overall research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not post the exact HTML code you want to have. Try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <html>
        <body> 
            <xsl:for-each select="info/catalog">
                <xsl:text>Catalog Id: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Id" />
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <xsl:text>Attributes:</xsl:text>
                <br/>
                <xsl:for-each select="books/book">
                    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
                        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        <br/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <br/>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! Not sure why it was so difficult for me to find a solution like this.